# Will a suspended user get my 100 point bounty?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, suspension

A user was sadly suspended, and during the dark times of their suspension I awarded them my hard-earned 100 points in the form of a bounty. Their rep did not change when I awarded the bounty, for reasons that are only too obvious.

But then I started to have my doubts...

**Where are my points?**

**And will the suspended user get the points that belong to them when the suspension ends?**

**REFERENCES:**

> Depending on the severity of the problem behavior — and at the complete discretion of the moderator — your account will be placed in timed suspension for anywhere from 1 to 365 days. That means:
>
> - Your account will be locked at 1 reputation.
> - Your user page will have a visual indication that you are in timed suspension, and for how long.
> - You will be unable to vote, ask, answer, or comment.
>
> At the end of this timed suspension period, your reputation will be recalculated, and your account will resume as normal.

*Jeff Atwood: A Day in the Penalty Box: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/*

Comment: This question might be a better fit for meta.SE because the issue is not specific to this community but rather a general issue with the software. It might likely be even already answered there.

Comment: Note that this answer sounds a bit abstract after all the edits. The Q is about the opaque accounting system of the bounty points, the points that seem to be vanishing into a black hole left by actions against this one user. Rest assured, there was a **real** user. And my points are also very real, and I am not kidding about getting them out of the black hole. **The user's name got edited out per rules of this site** (np, I am all for following the rules). I quote from the edit history: *removed reference to individual user - per meta guidance: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289909*

Comment: Can't see any problem with the mod's edit to your Q. For you personally it seems to matter who the user in question is. For almost everyone else the abstract question is more informative, in this case. The mod's edit was pretty much in line with the suggestion from https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289909/should-any-meta-post-that-calls-out-a-user-by-name-be-deleted-not-just-downvote See 1st bullet there under "our solution".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My understanding is the "locked at 1 reputation" part of a suspension is just a visual thing, and reputation is still gained/lost like normal behind the scenes.

From [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125268/my-account-has-been-temporarily-suspended-what-does-that-mean) on the main Meta site:

> Earned reputation points (rep) are reinstated. This may be different from the rep value at the start of the suspension because your posts may have been upvoted, downvoted or deleted during the suspension period, and some of your votes may have been invalidated.

And [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299465/can-a-bounty-be-awarded-to-a-temporarily-suspended-user) is a bit older, but specifically says rep from bounties is reinstated like any other rep:

> After the end of suspension, their reputation will be recalculated and it will include the bounty score and other reputation earned in the suspension period.

That second post also mentions that you'll be able to see the rep increase reflected in the 'reputation' tab of a suspended user's account. I don't think there's a rep requirement to see a user's rep gains or losses, so if you go to the reputation section of their account and click on the reputation graph you should be able to see the bounty and any other rep changes:

[image: Image of an account's reputation list showing a 100 rep bounty]

Comment: You are correct about being locked at 1 rep while they are suspended

Comment: @Giter Thank you for the quick and complete answer! Yes, that `+100` bounty "56 min ago" was me indeed. :)